# Significant Performance Difference of Conjugate Gradient Algorithm on Geforce 480 and Tesla C2070

Tags: gpu

I am running a Conjugate Gradient algorithm solving a linear system, which is size of 96 x 96. Using the same code, same numbers of iterations, and same accuracy (double precision), the time consuming on Geforce 480 is about 33.6 ms, while on Tesla C2070 is about 132.1 ms, almost 4 times comparing to Geforce 480!

Does this look normal to you? Does anyone experience similar results, or did I do something wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbling on this post when looking for conjugate gradient.

For this matrix size (96x96), the conjugate gradient is just overkill: you may use Cholesky decomposition, which should be much faster.
Similarly, using a GPU doesn't seem useful, except if you solve a bunch of them in parallel.

For the performance difference, there may be various explanations, but I would suggest that the iterative part of the CG algorithm is probably limiting - due to the system's size, once again: the Geforce may be better at latency and to communicate with the CPU.